# Compare array of objects and merge data if matched

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to compare objects in array of objects based on a property value if property value of two objects match then I want to merge them
my data looks like the below given array of objects.

```
[{
        "master": "filpkart",
        "business": [{
                "label": "flipkart process",
                "value": "flipkart.process"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "master": "amazon",
        "business": [{
                "label": "amazon process",
                "value": "amazon.process"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "master": "chat",
        "business": [{
                "label": "chat process",
                "value": "chat.process"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "master": "flipkart",
        "business": [{
                "label": "flipkart1 process",
                "value": "flipkart1.process"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

after comparing the above arary of objects my output should look like this

```
[{
        "master": "filpkart",
        "business": [{
                "label": "flipkart process",
                "value": "flipkart.process"
            },
            {
                "label": "flipkart1 process",
                "value": "flipkart1.process"
            }
            
        ]
    }, {
        "master": "amazon",
        "business": [{
                "label": "amazon process",
                "value": "amazon.process"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "master": "chat",
        "business": [{
                "label": "chat process",
                "value": "chat.process"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

could anyone please tell me how can I achieve this

Comment: what does not work? please add your code.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have no idea how to approach this

Answer (score 3):

Just play with Map:

```
const input = [{
  "master": "flipkart",
  "business": [{
          "label": "flipkart process",
          "value": "flipkart.process"
      }
  ]
}, {
  "master": "amazon",
  "business": [{
          "label": "amazon process",
          "value": "amazon.process"
      }
  ]
}, {
  "master": "chat",
  "business": [{
          "label": "chat process",
          "value": "chat.process"
      }
  ]
}, {
  "master": "flipkart",
  "business": [{
          "label": "flipkart1 process",
          "value": "flipkart1.process"
      }
  ]
}];

const result = Array.from(input.reduce((itemMap, value) => {
  if (itemMap.has(value.master)) {
    const business = itemMap.get(value.master).business.concat(value.business);
    itemMap.set(value.master, {...value, business });
  } else {
    itemMap.set(value.master, value);
  }

  return itemMap;
}, new Map()).values());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two `master: "flipkart"`, you could take an object fro grouping and get the values as result set.

```js
const
    data = [{ master: "flipkart", business: [{ label: "flipkart process", value: "flipkart.process" }] }, { master: "amazon", business: [{ label: "amazon process", value: "amazon.process" }] }, { master: "chat", business: [{ label: "chat process", value: "chat.process" }] }, { master: "flipkart", business: [{ label: "flipkart1 process", value: "flipkart1.process" }] }],
    grouped = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { master, business }) => {
        r[master] ??= { master, business: [] };
        r[master].business.push(...business);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and `forEach`

```js
let data = [{
  "master": "flipkart",
  "business": [{
    "label": "flipkart process",
    "value": "flipkart.process"
  }]
}, {
  "master": "amazon",
  "business": [{
    "label": "amazon process",
    "value": "amazon.process"
  }]
}, {
  "master": "chat",
  "business": [{
    "label": "chat process",
    "value": "chat.process"
  }]
}, {
  "master": "flipkart",
  "business": [{
    "label": "flipkart1 process",
    "value": "flipkart1.process"
  }]
}]
// initiate a new map 
let map = new Map();
data.forEach((item) => {
  // check if map have a key same as value of master in current object in iteration
  const mapData = map.get(item.master);
  // if not the set the key like flipkart, amazon..
  if (!mapData) {
    map.set(item.master, item)
  } else {
   // if already have the key the update the business array 
    map.get(item.master).business = map.get(item.master).business.concat(item.business)
  }

});
let formattedArr = []
// converting array of arrays 
for (let [k, v] of map.entries()) {
  formattedArr.push(v)

};
console.log(formattedArr)
```